# JSON.NET: check first key value in Json file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, json.net

I want to check the value of first tag in JSON. I did following:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@response);        
switch (o.First.ToString())
{
    case "players":
    {
        //do something
    }
    case "errors":
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

When I try to print o.first.tostring() I get the entire JSON string and not the first tag. What's wrong here?
Edit: I don't know if JSON recieved will be :`{Players:{"id":"xyz"}}` or `{errors:{"id":"123"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your case (with the provided JSON format) it will be something like:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(response);

switch (o.First.First.Path)
{
    case "Players":
        // do stuff 
        break;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And what does path? do Also no `ToString()`?